# JavaScript: Regex for two char Country codes

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to regex for these 3 two-chared country codes: de,fr,es in JavaScript.

```
/^(de|fr|es)/i
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how the string exactly looks, you have several options:

```
/^(?:de|fr|es)$/ // string contains only county code

/\b(?:de|fr|en)\b/ // looking for word boundaries 
                   // so it matches "en" but not "english"
```

Most likely you don't need a capturing group, that's why use `(?:)` to make it non-capturing.

Answer (score 1):

If it is all the string contains, then you should also check that the string ends there,

```
/^(?:de|fr|es)$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. But it works with "fr" and "french" too.
Here is an amazing web to test regular expressions:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that it doesn't match french by looking for word boundries.

```
/\b(de|fr|es)\b/i
```

This would match `fr` in any of these examples `fr,de` or `fr de` or `fr-de`, but not in `france` or `freedom`

Might be more specific to what you are looking for.

Comment: `/\b[de|fr|es]\b/i.test('e') === true` You're using the wrong kind of bracket.